# Iterate through list of url's with start and Stop button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of URL's and i need it to run as slide show on Start and Stop Of button. Currently it is running as a slideshow with out start and stop button.

Additionally I need to design a homepage with thumbnail of all those URL's.On click of thumbnail it has to redirect to that page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var urls = ["URL1", "URL2", "URL3","URL4", "URL5", "URL6","URL7", "URL8", "URL9"];
        var i = 0;
        function loadIframe(url)
        {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
        }

        setInterval(function() {
          // update the index
          i = (i + 1) % urls.length; 
          loadIframe(urls[i]); 
        }, 13000);

        loadIframe(urls[i]); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger the setInterval and save it, to clear it later.

```
var intvl = false; //Global Variable

$('#StartButton').on('click', function() 
{ 
  (!intvl) ? intvl = setInterval(...) : return; 
});

$('#StopButton').on('click', function() 
{ 
  clearInterval(intvl);
  intvl = false;
});
```

EDIT: changed to disable multiple intervals

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by storing `setInterval` in a variable so that you can use `clearInterval()` on it. `clearInterval()` will allow you to stop/pause the `setInterval` you created.

You also don't need the `$(function() {...})` component anymore as you will be the one controlling when the slider starts/stops:

```js
var slideInterval;
var urls = ["URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5", "URL6", "URL7", "URL8", "URL9"];
var i = 0;

function loadIframe(url) {
  //$('#iframe').attr('src', url);
  $('#iframe').html(url);
}

function start() {
  if (!slideInterval) { // If an interval is already in-use (ie if the slider is running) don't allow another slider to be made -> continue using the current one.
    slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
      // update the index
      i = (i + 1) % urls.length;
      loadIframe(urls[i]);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function stop() {
  if (slideInterval) { // If an interval doe exsist, we can then clear it, if it doesn't exsist then we have no interval to "clear", and so we don't run this code if one isn't in use
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = null;
  }
}

loadIframe(urls[0]);
```

```css
#iframe {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></div>

<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Not working.. It is not navigating. It is showing URL oly

Comment: @Nk88 you can’t use my code exactly as I’ve create an example so it works for this site. So you need to make sure your using an iframe instead of a div and that ur chasing the attribute src rather than the HTML in the loadIframe function

Comment: Any idea about how to create a thumbnail image of all those urls before clicking start

Comment: @Nk88 easiest way would be to create another image which has all the images in it and set that to be the first URL